# How to do a modular exponentiation?

Tags: modular-arithmetic

How to solve a problem like this:

Let $N = 11$. What is $2^{2652557887263} \pmod N$?

As part of the questions we are given the multiplication table for $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$:

```
x | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9  10
---------------------------------
1 | 1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9 10
2 | 2  4  6  8 10  1  3  5  7  9
3 | 3  6  9  1  4  7 10  2  5  8
4 | 4  8  1  5  9  2  6 10  3  7
5 | 5 10  4  9  3  8  2  7  1  6
6 | 6  1  7  2  8  3  9  4 10  5
7 | 7  3 10  6  2  9  5  1  8  4
8 | 8  5  2 10  7  4  1  9  6  3
9 | 9  7  5  3  1 10  8  6  4  2
10|10  9  8  7  6  5  4  3  2  1
```

...as well as $(\mathbb{Z}_{11}^*,\times)$, the group of units of $\mathbb{Z}_{11}$ under multiplication:

```
exp|  0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   10
 ------------------------------------------------
 g | g^0 g^1 g^2 g^3 g^4 g^5 g^6 g^7 g^8 g^9 g^10
 ------------------------------------------------
 1 |  1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1   1
 2 |  1   2   4   8   5  10   9   7   3   6   1
 3 |  1   3   9   5   4   1   3   9   5   4   1
 4 |  1   4   5   9   3   1   4   5   9   3   1
 5 |  1   5   3   4   9   1   5   3   4   9   1
 6 |  1   6   3   7   9  10   5   8   4   2   1
 7 |  1   7   5   2   3  10   4   6   9   8   1
 . |
 10|  1  10   1  10   1  10   1  10   1  10   1
```

Overall, I'm having trouble understanding **how the numbers in the table are generated, and how they're used to solve the aforementioned question**.

Answer (score 2):

The second row of the second table gives you the values of $g^e\pmod{11}$ for $0 \le e \le 10$. Notice that $2^{10}\pmod{11} \equiv 2^{0}\pmod{11}$. This means that $2^{10}$ raised to any power is congruent to $1\pmod{11}$.

With that in mind, it shouldn't be hard to see that $2^{2652557887263}\pmod{11} \equiv 2^3\pmod{11}$. So the answer is $8$.

---

<sup>P.S. I suspect your question may be slightly off-topic for this site, hence the down votes.</sup>

Comment: I think I'm starting to see it, but I'm still a little unsure. So suppose I had 2^235422656452414554 (mod 11), would that be 2^4 (mod 11), or 16?

Comment: There is no "$16$" in $\mathbb{Z}_{11} = \{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10\}$

Answer (score 0):

Modular exponentiation is done by [Square and Multiply](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation_by_squaring). And usually after each step the modulo operation is used.

And large exponents as in your example can be reduced by [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), with the special case of $n$ being prime covered by [Fermat's little theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fermat%27s_little_theorem).

With that, you can actually calculate an equivalent exponent to $x$ as $ x' = x\mod \phi(n)$. In your example $\phi(n) = 10$ you get $2652557887263 = 3 \mod 10$

Edit: In general when dealing with modular arithmetic, you're not actually calculating with the usual [integers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer) - we just use those integers are representations for so-called *congruence classes*, see the chapter about that in [Wikipedia on modular arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Integer).